# Inserting Date in DBase III DBF file using OleDB

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf, dbase

I'm trying to insert rows in a DBase III DBF file and I keep keeting type mismatch error on Date column. Column is Date(8,0)

I am using

```
OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;

.....
receipt.date = rdr.GetDateTime(1); - creating a list of receipts from a SQLite DB
.....
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO decont (cod, data)" + " VALUES (?, ?)";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", Convert.ToInt32(receipts[j].c_id));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", receipts[j].date); // tried converting parsing
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried n types of Formatting and Parsing, even manually trying to insert using {date} {^date} and nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line `cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", receipts[j].date);`
to: `cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", receipts[j].Value.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the parameter names "@", just leave as a parameter name.  You appear to be on-target with your AddWithValue() calls.  It may be just failing on the data types you THINK you are converting to apply to your command.  You may want to break it up before posting.  Also, to prevent confusion on parameters vs column names in a table select/insert/update, I try to prefix them with "p" to differentiate and help avoid confusion of a column vs parameter.

Correct use of the "?" place-holders for the parameter passing, AND adding the parameters in the correct sequence as the "?" represent in the command.

```
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO decont (cod, data) VALUES (?, ?)";

var myInt = Convert.ToInt32(receipts[j].c_id);
var myDate = receipts[j].date;

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", myInt );
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", myDate ); 
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now, I have not explicitly tested for valid data conversion, but if you don't get an int and date respectively for the myInt and myDate, then the SQL Insert will obviously fail.

For grins, and testing, just to make sure your query works, try doing with known legit values, such as:

```
var myInt = 3;
var myDate = DateTime.Now;

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", myInt );
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", myDate );
```

Then you KNOW you have proper data types and can confirm if the insert function works or not.  If the database file is a DATE vs DATETIME, you may need to drop it down to

```
// to strip off any time component portion and have it fail.
var myDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Additionally, if your table has other columns and they don't allow null and must be provided, that too would make the insert fail.